# how to verify complete payment details for future payments via stripe rest api

Tags: payment-gateway, credit-card, stripe-payments

#### create token with credit card details

```
token_response = stripe.Token.create(
    card={
        "number": card_number,
        "exp_month": card_expiry_month,
        "exp_year": card_expiry_year,
        "cvc": security_code,

        # adding optional data
        "address_line1": billing_address_1,
        "address_line2": billing_address_2,
        "address_city": billing_city,
        "address_state": billing_state,
        "address_zip": billing_zip_code,
        "name": card_holder_name
    },
)
```

#### create customer and link it with above token

```
stripe.Customer.create(
    name=card_holder_name, description=" description",
    email=email, source=token_response['id']
)
```

#### session checkout with setup mode

```
setup_intent_for_customer = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
    payment_method_types=['card'],
    mode='setup',
    customer=strip_customer_obj['id'],
    confirm=True
)
```

### Problem is that above is only verifying card number and its cvc code but not card holder name, card expiry date & billing address without deduction of amount from card. how can i verify complete credit card details without payment deduction ?

Comment: You want to follow https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse which will set up a card for future usage without an initial payment.

Comment: i am Collecting payment details using Checkout’s setup mode as mentioned in first tab of shared link. but it is not verifying all details.it is only verifying card number and cvc code

Comment: If you believe it's verifying bad information as correct, I'd suggest reaching out to [Stripe](https://support.stripe.com/email) directly as they can confirm if that's the case. Setup mode will verify the card with the issuing bank. You may also need to check your Radar settings in the Stripe Dashboard.